# laravel 4 rewrite url for pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination, laravel-4

I use Laravel pagination but the url are like this :

```
http://mydomain.com/?page=2
```

I prefere to have url like this :

```
http://mydomain.com/page/2
```

I have the htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I try the line :

```
RewriteRule ^/([0-9])$ index.php?page=$1
```

But itt doesn't work... Any idea ? Can use something else than the `.htaccess` file ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand Laravel's default pagination system does not support the kind of routing your are looking for.

Since your routes can look very differently for each page in your application is hard to come with a catch all RewriteRule in .htaccess that will properly rewrite the URL in a format that Laravel will understand while also not messing about with other URL parameters and paths.

---

For your specific example, *but this will work ONLY for your specific example and nothing else*, you could try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    #Handle pagination for urls like http://mydomain.com/page/2
    RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Again, this **is not a general** solution and will work only for links like http://mydomain.com/page/2 (and not for links like http://mydomain.com/users/page/2)